# Invalid anonymous type member declarator

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the following code which should work, according to [this MSDN Forums post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b13432a-861e-45f0-8c25-4d54622fbfb4/linq-group-and-sum-table#2de2d0a7-b87a-4b49-b6df-637bffa405ae).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace LINQTest
{
    class Program
    {
        class Schedule
        {
            public int empid { get; set; }
            public int hours { get; set; }
            public DateTime date { get; set; }
            public DateTime weekending { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Schedule> Schedules = new List<Schedule>();

            var bla = from s in Schedules
                      group s by new { s.empid, s.weekending} into g
                      select new { g.Key.empid, g.Key.weekending, g.Sum(s=>s.hours)};
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error with the sum function:
Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

What's wrong?

Comment: What should the name of the property `g.Sum(s=>s.hours)` be?

Comment: Give your anonymous type member names :)

Comment: @retailcoder Only one needs a name.

Comment: you're all correct. I need to name the property.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You have to name the property used to store `Sum` method result:

```
select new { g.Key.empid, g.Key.weekending, Sum = g.Sum(s=>s.hours)};
```

Compiler can't infer the property name when you're assigning the value from expression:

[Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx)

> You must provide a name for a property that is being initialized with an expression (...)