# how to convert a date-time in string in C#mvc5 so that it doesnot get null date time value

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating a project, in which I want to store a date from my database in a list. I use MVC5 and C#. In the corresponding controller, I passed the value from the database as:

```
var order1 = (from a in context.DB_OrderDetails
              where a.OrderId == id
              select new
              { 
                  a.ActualCompletedAt,
              }).ToList();
```

and in script I wrote

```
for (i = 0; i < result.order1.length; i++) {
    str += '<tr>';
    str += '<td> ' + order1[i].ActualCompletedAt + '</td>';
    str += '<tr/>';
}
```

But in list  I get value as date/878978978979 etc. 
in database it is like " 2015-09-24 14:59:10.837" i.e. proper date and time.
what modification do I need to make in my Linq query so that date is not null?

Comment: What type is `ActualCompletedAt`?

Comment: What has this got to do with Null?  Where is the Null value?  "878978978979" is not null...

Comment: What datatype is `ActualCompletedAt`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856885/invalid-anonymous-type-member-declarator

Comment: this was basically what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `ToString` and format it properly:

```
ActualCompletedAt = a.ActualCompletedAt("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

I suppose that `ActualCompletedAt` is a `DateTime` object. If this is a nullable `DateTime` object, then you have to make a check first.

```
ActualCompletedAt = a.ActualCompletedAt != null ? a.ActualCompletedAt.Value("MM/dd/yyyy") : ""
```

Comment: @Priya then I think that the first does what you want. Please give it a go and let me know. Thanks

Comment: a.ActualCompletedAt("MM/dd/yyyy")  I changed this in controller but its giving error. and by null value i mean in some dates I am getting null value and in some I am getting garbage values

Comment: Assuming ActualCompletedAt is DateTime?  a.ActualCompletedAt != null ? a.ActualCompletedAt.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : ""

Comment: @Priya then please try the second version. In this case you have a nullable `DateTime`.

Comment: its giving this error "Datetime?Actualcompletedat.tostring " in Visual studio 2013

Comment: @Priya please try the second version and let me know.

Comment: tdbeckett: I tried this too but its giving an error saying invalid anonymous type declarator :/ what to do

Comment: Christos : a.ActualCompletedAt("MM/dd/yyyy"). this is what you mean by second version. its not working. what check I am supposed to do??

Comment: @Priya I mean this `a.ActualCompletedAt != null ? a.ActualCompletedAt.Value("MM/dd/yyyy") : ""`

Comment: yup can you suggest something else. I did both. Its saying Invalid anonymous type declarator!

Comment: @Priya Please try the updated version. It seems that there is a problem  with the naming of the property in the anonymous type you define. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856885/invalid-anonymous-type-member-declarator

Comment: @Christos: Thank you so much. This link really helped. Got my answer. thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the json serializer handles dates.  I'm sure there is a way to control how it's done but an easy fix is to return the date as a string in the controller, by appending .ToString() after ActualCompletedAt in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

(UPDATED)

I agree with PeteGO, that result doesn't look like it has anything to do with null values.

But to answer your question, to avoid nulls, you can use:

```
var order1 = (from a in context.DB_OrderDetails
                      where a.OrderId == id
                      and a.ActualCompletedAt != null
                      select new
                     { 
                        a.ActualCompletedAt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff"),
                     }).ToList();
```

then in script:

```
for (i = 0; i < result.order1.length; i++) {
    str += '<tr>';
    str += '<td> ' + order1[i].ActualCompletedAt + '</td>';
    str += '<tr/>';
}
```

Comment: I did this thing but I am showing my list ondblclick event and once I make this change in script that ondblclick event is not working :/

Comment: hmmm...   adding that "and" statement to the LINQ's where clause should not effect the events at all.  There must be something else going on.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not working".  Does it mean that your list is empty?  If so, are all of the values actually null?

Comment: I just realized that the second part of your code is in script, and I do not know how the formatting of the ToString() will work in script.  You can move the ToString("...") to the LINQ statement, then your list will be a list of strings already formatted.

Comment: I am getting values of Date in list in two formats-(a)Date(840878450) (b)Null. these two values are showing  instead of " 2015-09-24 14:59:10.837"

Comment: and When I add Tostring to Linq it is giving invalid anonymous type declaraotor error

Comment: I got the solution :)

Comment: OK, please let us know what solution was selected, or what else was wrong.