# How to make EF query who return aggregated values for many to many relation tables in MVC 5 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have this ADO.NET model:

[image: data-model]

I use MVC in view have [post] form to request one of reports.
In controller action who receive "FormCollection"- data i want to make query who return to me every Tags included in this Report and their values.

And here is one example of wanted return:

```
Report: A - this is name of report;
{ 

     [0]
       {
          TagName: TAG1
          Value: 0.56 - this value is aggregated value of all values for this tag1
       }
     [1]
       {
          TagName: TAG2
          Value: 2.45 -> this value is aggregated value of all values for this tag2 
       }
}
```

I tried to make like this but didn`t work:

```
 var report = db.Reports
                    .Where(r => r.ID == reportID)
                    .Select(r => new {
                        r.Name,
                        r.Tags
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

How to get related values for tags in this structures and aggregate them?

Comment: The value `0.56` is it the sum of all values that belong to TAG1 ?

Comment: Yes it is sum.But also can be Average or another aggregation of all values belongs to this tag.

Comment: Then the answer given by @teo-van-kot is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
            var report = db.Reports.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ID == reportID);
        var Tags = report.Tags
            .Select(t => new
            {
                TagName = t.Name,
                Values = t.Values
                        .Where(a => a.TimeStamp > startDate && a.TimeStamp <= endDate)
            }).Select(a => new {
                Name = a.TagName,
                Value = a.Values.Sum(s => s.Value1) })
            .ToList();
```

And result:

[image]

Thanks to all for help!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correct you want to get this structure in the end:

```
public class TagWithValue
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double ValueAggrigated { get; set; }
}

public class RemortTags
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<TagWithValue> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

You can fill this struture like this:

```
var report = db.Reports
                .Where(r => r.ID == reportID)
                .Select(r => new RemortTags {
                    Name = r.Name,
                    Tags = r.Tags.Select(x => new TagWithValue {
                               Name = x.Name,
                               ValueAggrigated = x.Sum(y => y.Value1) //that's where you should aggrigate your values. You can use different function if you want
                           })
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: The solution is close but when I try your code i receive error:
"Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access"

Comment: @NikolayDaskalov are you sure that you implement this like i write? Looks like you still use Anonymous object. If so you should write name for your `x.Sum(y => y.Value1)` line [here is an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18856933/1849444)